# SPO modern list view with multiple filters not filtering list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, filter, modern-experience

I have run into an issue where I create a view with the filters in the image below (the list is a modern list in SPO converted over from 13' to SPO by share gate). The issue is that I continue to see all of my list items previous to 2017 which date back to 2013. this seems like a Microsoft bug. Has anyone else experienced this and is there a workaround?

[image: SPO multi filter issue]

Comment: Check your 4th condition, you have added "is greater than" operator... Is it causing this issue?

Comment: no, we have tried all variations of the operator and it does not work as expected. it does work if I remove all filters except the date.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a  test in my SharePoint online list, when i filter with created is greater than a time, the items are displayed fine in the list.

[image]

Try to filter only with created is greater than 1/1/2017 and compare whether the issue exists.

Try to do a test in another list and compare whether the issue exists.

Comment: I have tried using the filter for date only and it works as expected. 

We have also tried testing in other lists and we can recreate in several sites and lists(newly created and existing lists)